# How to retrieve data directly from .json file present on GitHub?

Tags: json, dialogflow-es

I am developing a Dialogflow chatbot and I found an useful Q/A '.json' file on GitHub. Is it possible to retrieve data directly from GitHub to Dialogflow? if yes, how can I it ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you could try to make a GET request and trying to get a jsonp file.

But chances are, that GitHub doesn't allow CORS (Cross Origin Ressource Sharing).

You can only try it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch that file as a raw Github file which will have a similar link like this. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google-research/bert/master/sample_text.txt

Comment: Basically, I am trying to find a way to retrieve data directly online without any offline stuff. Is there a way to use Heroku or other services to do this ?